# Start intent for specific PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences

In my app, I have a `PreferenceActivity` which contains a `PreferenceFragment`, which in turn contains preferences added from an XML file with `addPreferencesFromResource(...)`. The preference hierarchy looks like this (somewhat simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_header_general">
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="My team"
            android:key="button_my_team_settings_key">

            <EditTextPreference
                android:title="Set team number"
                android:key="@string/preference_my_team"
                android:persistent="true"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

From elsewhere in my app, I want to link to a particular `PreferenceScreen` within my preferences, specifically "My team". Does the Android platform support this natively? Or will I have to send the desired `PreferenceScreen` via the intent and then manually handle switching to the appropriate screen?

Comment: One question at a time.

Comment: id like to know this too

Answer (score 0):

You can send an intent from elsewhere to do the same, but you will have to make a few changes. First of all, make a new Fragment class which contains the following in a separate xml file:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="My team"
    android:key="button_my_team_settings_key">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="Set team number"
        android:key="@string/preference_my_team"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:inputType="number"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

(I've lifted this segment from your own code.)
Next, in your code, for the root preferences screen, replace the inner `PreferenceScreen` with the following:

```
<Preference
    android:title="My Team"
    app:fragment="com.packagename.FragmentClassYouMade"/>
```

Now, you have a Fragment instead of a Subscreen to link to. A Fragment within the same activity can easily be displayed elsewhere.